# Active image tab image gallary

Tags: javascript, css

I have a tab gallery (from W3Schools) where you can choose an image to show under. I was wondering how to have an active class for the chosen image after I choose. Like when you see it on navbar (this example shows that pages is open).
(Home **pages** about contact)
I just need to give the clicked image any class(opacity or color) I tried many things but still new with JavaScript and couldn't achieve what I want:

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
  opacity: 0.8; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container */
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

/* Expanding image text */
#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Closable button inside the expanded image */
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Tabbed Image Gallery</h2>
  <p>Click on the images below:</p>
</div>

<!-- The four columns -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/222" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/201" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/209" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @saliem_autoun please mark your question as solved if one of the answers provided is satisfactory for that behavior you have requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventtarget/addeventlistener) that adds whatever classes you need and remove them. You can use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to access the element which triggered the listener and add/remove classes accordingly:

```js
// get the images that we want to listen for clicks from
let img = document.querySelectorAll(".column img");

// add an event listener to each image
img.forEach(function(elem) {
  // when one of the images is clicked, add the "your-class" class to it and remove the class from any other elements
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // check if any other elements have the class and remove it if some do
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".your-class").length != 0) {
      document.querySelector(".your-class").classList.remove("your-class");
      // if there are no other elements with "your-class" do nothing
    } else {}
    // add "your-class" to the element clicked
    event.target.classList.add("your-class")
  });
});
```

In the code snippet below, I have demonstrated this by having a class that changes the border of the active image to the color cyan when it is clicked:

```js
// get the images that we want to listen for clicks from
let img = document.querySelectorAll(".column img");

// add an event listener to each image
img.forEach(function(elem) {
  // when one of the images is clicked, add the border-cyan class to it and remove the class from any other elements
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // check if any other elements have the class and remove it if some do
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".border-cyan").length != 0) {
      document.querySelector(".border-cyan").classList.remove("border-cyan");
      // if there are no other elements with the border cyan class do nothing
    } else {}
    // add the border cyan class to the element clicked
    event.target.classList.add("border-cyan")
  });
});

function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}


/* Expanding image text */

#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.border-cyan {
  border: 3px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Tabbed Image Gallery</h2>
  <p>Click on the images below:</p>
</div>

<!-- The four columns -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/222" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/201" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/209" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so helpful, specially how you explain every step! <3 <3

Comment: No problem, always happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

1. at first you need to find all images and remove class from them
2. after that add class for clicked image

```js
function myFunction(img) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = img.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = img.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
  img.closest('.row').querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => img.classList.remove('yourClassName'))
  img.classList.add('yourClassName')
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
  opacity: 0.8; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container */
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

/* Expanding image text */
#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Closable button inside the expanded image */
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yourClassName {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Tabbed Image Gallery</h2>
  <p>Click on the images below:</p>
</div>

<!-- The four columns -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/222" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/201" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/209" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, simple and clear solution and solved what I needed! <3<3